# How to delete redundant records with different dates from a MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, redundancy

I have a table in a MySQL database that consists of the following columns:

```
itemID      bigint(11)
itemDate    datetime    
attributeID smallint(6)
value       int(9)
```

**Edit:** This table stores attributes for items uniquely defined in a separate table whose primary and relation key is **itemID**.

**What would be the SQL queries (?) to best delete** (*starting from most recent records to the oldest*):

- each record in this table that has **value** = 0 if exists (another record with the same **itemID** and same **attributeID** and that has a **value** >5 and the **itemDate** is (older but also most recent) OR identical)
- each record in this table if exists (another record with the same **itemID** and same **attributeID** and same **value** and the **itemDate** is (older but also most recent) OR identical)

*also see the code at the end*

I am using this in a PHP script.

Basically, I have redundant data due to a bug that I had not identified soon enough for it not to populate around 100k entries. A very small example below:

```
itemID  itemDate        attributeID value
28  11.09.2013 2:00     4           0
28  11.09.2013 2:00     5           0
28  11.09.2013 2:01     1           0
28  11.09.2013 2:01     2           0
28  11.09.2013 2:01     3           0
28  11.09.2013 2:01     4           0
28  11.09.2013 2:01     5           0
28  11.09.2013 2:02     1           21
28  11.09.2013 2:02     2           11
28  11.09.2013 2:02     3           4
28  11.09.2013 2:02     1           21
28  11.09.2013 2:02     2           11
28  11.09.2013 2:02     3           4
28  11.09.2013 2:02     1           21
28  11.09.2013 2:02     2           12
28  11.09.2013 2:02     3           4
28  13.09.2013 18:54    1           0
28  13.09.2013 18:54    2           0
28  13.09.2013 18:54    3           0
28  13.09.2013 18:55    1           21
28  13.09.2013 18:55    2           12
28  13.09.2013 18:55    3           6
```

The above should become (*after multiple iterations of the deletion algorythm*):

```
itemID  itemDate        attributeID value
28  11.09.2013 2:00     4           0
28  11.09.2013 2:00     5           0
28  11.09.2013 2:01     1           0
28  11.09.2013 2:01     2           0
28  11.09.2013 2:01     3           0
28  11.09.2013 2:02     1           21
28  11.09.2013 2:02     2           11
28  11.09.2013 2:02     3           4
28  11.09.2013 2:02     2           12
28  13.09.2013 18:55    3           6
```

I hope I defined the problem clear enough, however, please let me know if I should clarify anything.
Thank you kindly!

**UPDATE**

I managed to find a solution combining SQL with php, but I do not really like it. I do believe the same result can be obtained with 2 correct SQL queries, so, though I am satisfied I have the means to clean my database, the issue remains as in: How to translate the code below into pure sql queries.

```
// Properties
$item_found_count = $item_valid_count = 0;

// Find zero value entries
$query = "SELECT * FROM $db_fb WHERE value = '0'";

if ($result = mysqli_query($connection, $query)) {

    // for each record found
    while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {

        $item_found_count++;    // Count all items found
        $t_itemID = $row['itemID']; $t_itemDate = $row['itemDate']; $t_attributeID = $row['attributeID'];   // Record this data just in case we need it as a 'pointer' to delete the record

        //echo "Entry found: " . $row['itemID'] . " " . $row['itemDate'];

        $query = "SELECT * FROM $db_fb WHERE itemID = $t_itemID AND itemDate < '$t_itemDate' AND attributeID = '$t_attributeID' AND value > '5' ORDER BY itemDate DESC LIMIT 1";
        // If there is such an entry, the current one must be deleted.
        if ($SecondResult = mysqli_query($connection, $query)) {

            while($rowSpec = $SecondResult->fetch_array()) {
            $item_valid_count++;    // Count all items actually deleted

                //echo "<br>-> mark;"; print_r($rowSpec); echo "<br>";

                // Delete if ID, itemDate, attributeID and VALUE coincide
                $q_del = "DELETE FROM $db_fb WHERE itemID = $t_itemID AND itemDate = '$t_itemDate' AND attributeID = '$t_attributeID' AND value = '0'";
                $deleteRes = mysqli_query($connection, $q_del);

            }

        }

        //echo "--------------------------<br><br>";
    }

}

// Select from table where values are identical, attributeID identical, ID identical, itemDates immediately consecutive LIMIT by 2. Delete most recent entry.
$query = "SELECT MAX(itemDate) as itemDate, itemID, attributeID, value, count(*) FROM $db_fb GROUP BY itemID, attributeID, value HAVING count(*) > 1 ORDER BY itemDate DESC";

    if ($ThirdResult = mysqli_query($connection, $query)) {

            while($rowSpec = $ThirdResult->fetch_array()) {
            $item_duplicates_count++;   // Count all items actually deleted

                $t_itemID = $rowSpec['itemID']; $t_itemDate = $rowSpec['itemDate']; $t_attributeID = $rowSpec['attributeID'];   $t_value = $rowSpec['value']; // Record this data just in case we need it as a 'pointer' to delete the record

                //echo "<br>-> mark;"; print_r($rowSpec); echo "<br>";
                $q_del = "DELETE FROM $db_fb WHERE itemID = '$t_itemID' AND itemDate = '$t_itemDate' AND attributeID = '$t_attributeID' AND value = '$t_value'";
                $deleteRes = mysqli_query($connection, $q_del);


            }

        }

echo "Zeroed found: " . $item_found_count . "<br>";
echo "Zeroed valid for deletion: " . $item_valid_count . "<br>";
echo "Zeroed remaining: " . ($item_found_count - $item_valid_count) . "<br>";

echo "Consecutive duplicates: " . $item_duplicates_count;
```

Comment: Can you tell me what are the **primary keys** in your relation (table)?

Comment: @leoMestizo Hi, i edited my question, but I will also mention here that the attributes belong to items uniquely defined in a separate table by itemID key.

Comment: Yes, but **itemID** is the PK in this table? If so, you didn't respect the *UNIQUENESS* property on candidate keys.

Comment: @leoMestizo **itemID** is not a primary key in this table because there are multiple historical records associated with a single item and they are all stored to keep a record of the attribute evolution in time when needed.

*This* table does not have a primary key.

Comment: You can have a table without PK... But why? I think that you have to "rethink" your design... If you want, I can help you! I don't have problem with that... If you want we can move this conversation to chat. Cheers!

Comment: @leoMestizo Hello again. There is no actual need for a PK in this table. Considering also there will be a lot of entries, I decided not to include a PK.

However, I edited my question posting a solution that includes a bit of php as well. The question remains, how to resolve this purely with sql, so I am hoping the code above explains the problem a bit better.

Have a great day!